# Ubuntu 14.04 asks to downgrade packages?

Tags: package-management, 14.04, aptitude, downgrade

I'm new to ubuntu, so please excuse any naive questions.
After a fresh install of 14.04, I was adding apps from the Software Center, but most of them continued to fail because "Package Dependencies could not be resolved". Here is an example for trying to install guake :

```
guake: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
       Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but 2.40.0-2 is to be installed
       Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
       Depends: libpython2.7 (>= 2.7) but 2.7.6-8 is to be installed
       Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
```

After trying a variety of things with apt-get (update, clean, install -f, etc.), I saw a suggestion to install aptitude. But, now aptitude suggests that I should downgrade my packages :

```
 Downgrade the following packages:                               
1)     python-gtk2 [2.24.0-3ubuntu3 (now) -> 2.24.0-3ubuntu1 (saucy)]
```

This seems to be asking me to downgrade to the version of the previous Ubuntu version (saucy salamander), and similarly for most apps that I'm trying to install.
What should I do? Downgrade the packages? Or just install Ubuntu 13.10?

PS : My software sources are the default ones + canonical partners.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: What I'm asking is different - not how to resolve them, but should I downgrade packages/ubuntu to resolve them?

Comment: It is difficult to give a definitive answer to you.  But I can say in the general sense that I have on occasion been stuck in a loop where I need to downgrade or uninstall something in order to get something installed.  Sometimes, I say yes to uninstalling something and then I install it back after the resolver is happy.  The resolver sometimes gets it wrong; just take note of what you are agreeing to have uninstalled and when the conflicts are resolved, install them back in.  This is not professional advice; just my own experience, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well am no expert myself, but it seems this is a result of a small lag in the dependencies moving up to speed to the released 14.04 base system.

What I understand is that the base system has moved on to newer packages, but some installed application(s) may still be stuck up using some older version of the packages (which would need to ask you to downgrade to their level to function).

I guess you may just ignore these errors, and avoid using these applications for a few days for the devs to push through the newer and fixed versions of these applications.

Alternatively, you may also downgrade some packages if it does not break some other dependency (which I suspect it would)